Copying files in network share from folder to folder
I'm trying to copy files on a network share from one folder to another, so I'm just doing copy and paste, I have TeraCopy installed and it shows a speed of 2KB/s to 7KB/s.
I'm working from home and the share is accessed via VPN.
My question is, is this like a normal copy in my own machine?
Are the files going from folder A to folder B without going through my computer?
Should I start the copy operation via terminal in the destination machine? If so how do i start the copy operation and leave it running even if I disconnect/close the terminal window?


My question is, is this like a normal copy in my own machine? Are the files going from folder A to folder B without going through my computer?

It depends on the software and the protocol being used. Run "Task Manager" and look at your network usage graph to find out – if you copy a big file and see a spike in the "Network" graph, then it's going through your computer.
SMBv3 (standard Windows file sharing) supports optional "Server-side copy", where the SMB client can tell the server to copy from A to B and it all happens server-side. However, this is an optional feature and not guaranteed to be supported with every server, in which case the only remaining option would be to do all copying client-side, where your computer has to download everything from A and then upload back to B.
Also, "server-side copy" only takes effect if the client software specifically uses the operation – e.g. the Windows built-in copy function does, but TeraCopy probably does not. (Such tools deliberately implement copying from scratch to make things faster locally, but the downside is that they often ignore or forget such optimizations.)
So if TeraCopy uses the traditional approach to file copying (read from A, write to B, read from A, write to B), then everything indeed goes through your computer first – and then back to the server, going through the VPN both ways.
(It could also be an old server or NAS running outdated software that doesn't support server-side copy, or it could even be a server using the obsolete SMBv1, in which case the copy again needs to go through your computer because there's no other way to do it.)

Should I start the copy operation via terminal in the destination machine? If so how do i start the copy operation and leave it running even if I disconnect/close the terminal window?

With a Linux or BSD server, there are two options:

If you just want a fire-and-forget method, run the copy command as nohup <cmd> & (for example, nohup cp -av /this /that &).

If you want something persistent (to check up later), first run tmux or screen if either of those is installed, then run your commands inside – it creates a persistent session that you can re-attach later to see the status/progress (e.g. tmux a[ttach] or screen -R).


I'm not sure if Windows servers have any equivalent option for running a detached process through SSH or PS-Remoting, but if you connect via Remote Desktop then the copy should continue running after you disconnect.
(Unless the server has been deliberately set up to log you off after disconnecting, in which case there's nothing you can really do.)
You can also do the copy from a local terminal using robocopy \\nas\old \\nas\new /e (the robocopy tool comes built-in with Windows).

Task Manager shows that it is indeed going through my computer.

Sounds like you should try disabling TeraCopy for network shares – it's possible that the server already supports SSC and Windows would use it automatically.

I forget because it's a Network Share mounted on a Windows Machine but it's a QNAP NAS, according to this PDF I found pages 4 and 4 it should support SSC, sadly I don't see an option to disable teracopy only for network shares, I'll make it prompt what to use teracopy or default windows.

Using the windows built in copy still shows a slight spike in network traffic but it 130Mb/s from teracopy vs 3Mb/s from built in, it's also way faster (On a 250MB file I used to test)

Well, there will always be a slight spike because the client still needs to scan all old directories and issue the create & copy commands for each file separately, but it should be easy to distinguish that from the much heavier "all data being downloaded/reuploaded" rise in network usage. (Although I have to say, <10 KB/s is really slow even through VPN – even my home ADSL used to be faster.)

< 10KB/s might be because it's a bunch of small files AND through WIFI
